# C# TCP Server and reading strings sent to the server to activate a function

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I want to use my remote to activate a function on my c# application via TCP/IP.

I have a program running on my remote that has a code like this, which sends the string "turnoff" to a TCP/IP server client: The 10.1.1.17 is the local ip of the computer, and the 898 is the port that is listening for incoming things.

```
socket1 = socket.connect("10.1.1.17", 898)
socket.send(socket1, "turnoff\n")
```

Firstly, how do I use this string of text, 'hello', to activate a function in my .net c# application? For example, if I send the string of 'turnoff', and I have a function in the c# app called 'turnoff()', how do I call this function.

One idea I had was to create a textbox and have the program read the text from the 'recieved data' box and if it is recognized, activate the necessary function. A program that would look something like this: http://gyazo.com/5419901b55fcf404a627b67bdee492f5 . How do I recreate this?

But, this doesn't seem like the most efficient method, reading strings from a textbox. Surely there is another way to read the "hello" message or any string into the c# program and activate a function within it.

Also, how do I create a TCP/IP server in C# with an port that listens for incoming strings and can send things back to the client connecting to it? For example, if I connect to the c# server with my remote, and I press a button on the C# form to send a string back to the remote. Is this called asynchronous or something, I'm not really sure.

Thanks.

Comment: You have way too many problems here in one question, break the problem apart in to smaller peices, try to figure out how to do each one, if you get stuck, come back here with that specific part's problem.

Comment: Better look up on WCF. That is much easier to use and maintain than directly using raw sockets and TCP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @ganesh-r do you use wcf in windows forms or .aspx or ?

Comment: We use it in a WPF client as well as a console based .NET service

Answer (score 0):

You can use my open source library.

## The server

As a server you typically just create a ChannelTcpListener:

```
var settings = new ChannelTcpListenerConfiguration(
    () => new MicroMessageDecoder(new DataContractSerializer()),
    () => new MicroMessageEncoder(new DataContractSerializer())
    );

var server = new MicroMessageTcpListener(settings);
server.MessageReceived = OnServerMessage;

server.Start(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
```

That’s it, all you need now is a callback to receive messages from all clients:

```
private static void OnServerMessage(ITcpChannel channel, object message)
{
    var command = (DeviceCommand) message;
    //do something with the command
}
```

## The client

In the client you do about the same, but you use async/await instead of a callback.

```
private static async Task RunClient()
{
    var client = new ChannelTcpClient<object>(
        new MicroMessageEncoder(new DataContractSerializer()),
        new MicroMessageDecoder(new DataContractSerializer())
        );

    await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3"), 1234);
    await client.SendAsync(new DeviceCommand("turnoff"));
    await client.CloseAsync();
}
```

Install the nuget package "griffin.framework" to use it. Code available at [github](http://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.framework)